# How can i use math operations in Aggregate Functions?

Tags: sql-server, aggregate-functions

I have question about Tsql. How can I write this query in Sql Server using math operations in **`Count()`**?

For example:

```
 Declare @Result int
 SELECT E.FirstName,E.LastName,E.Register,E.trans,
 FROM CTE E
 @Result = Count(trans/register = 0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you can't assign variables and do data retrieval in the same statement. Your statement in the count is also not valid. What is it exactly that you want to do?

Try changing it like this

```
 Declare @Result int
 Select @Result = Count(trans/register)
 FROM CTE E
```